# Error, "No package.xml found", when I try to save static resources and/or apex classes using Sublime 3 w/ Lightning package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, package, sublime, force-cli

I am working on a Salesforce project using Sublime Text 3 as my IDE.

I've installed "[force cli](https://force-cli.herokuapp.com)" to my machine and to Sublime Text 3 I installed the package "[Lightning](https://github.com/dcarroll/sublime-lightning)".

On the "Lightning" menu that opens when I right click on a file within Sublime Text 3 side bar files browser, I can login to my org and fetch aura bundles, classes and static resources, however, I can only deploy aura components. When I save a class or a static resource I get the following error:

> Failures - 1
>
> "package.xml", line 0: Error No package.xml found

On the console I get the following:

> [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\develop\sublime-src\testpoject\metadata\classes\My_Util.cls\*.*'

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have MavensMate also installed? If so you might try temporarily disabling the MM package in Package Control and see if that helps.

Comment: The error was occurring with a new install of SublimeText 3. After running into this error, I have installed MM, and that is working fine.

Comment: To be honest, I've not used the sublime lightning for editing other metadata. I've been doing a kind of hybrid development editing all LCF files using sublime lightning, and the rest in MM. This means two different ST3 windows open, two different directories. It's not pretty, but so far it works ok.

Comment: I am facing the same problem here. Using the lightning package on Sublime Text 3 I can fetch my static resources but I can not deploy it (deploy happens automatically when I save a file). A coworker has the same setup and using my files he can deploy with no problems. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Disregard my edit please. I got mixed up with my browser windows and edit your question instead of ask a new one each i did now at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84914/error-no-package-xml-found-when-i-try-to-save-static-resources-and-or-apex-c .