# Error, "No package.xml found", when I try to save static resources and/or apex classes using Sublime 3 w/ Lightning package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sublime, force-cli

I am working on a Salesforce project using Sublime Text 3 as my IDE.

I have a salesforce developer account. I have a pc running windows 8.

I've installed "[force cli](https://force-cli.herokuapp.com)" to my computer and to Sublime Text 3 I installed the package "[Lightning](https://github.com/dcarroll/sublime-lightning)".

I have my project root at C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\salesforce\ .

On the"Lightning" menu that opens when I right click on a file within Sublime Text 3 side bar files browser, I can login to my org and fetch aura bundles, classes and static resources, however, I can only deploy aura components. When I save a change on a class or a static resource I get the following error:

> Failures - 1
>
> "package.xml", line 0: Error No package.xml found

On the console I get the following when saving a change on a class file:

> Type: ApexClass
>   Item: AwesomeProductController
>   Running force fetch -t ApexClass -n AwesomeProductController -unpack
>
> [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\salesforce\metadata\classes\AwesomeProductController.cls\*.*'
>   Running force push -f=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\salesforce\metadata\classes\AwesomeProductController.cls

On the console I get the following when saving a change on a Static Resource file:

> [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\salesforce\metadata\staticresources\coreStyles.resource\*.*'
>   Running force push -f=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\salesforce\metadata\staticresources\coreStyles.resource

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a solution for your problem specifically, but HaoIDE also supports Lightning development and is under more active development than sublime-lightning: https://github.com/xjsender/haoide .  Might be worth a try.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with haoIDE. The demo looks good. I'll read the documentation and might give it a shot, but I still would like a solution for the problem. I have the same setup on different machines and this problem only happens on a fraction of them.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana, some demos are not newest, you should have a try on it, if you ran into any problem, you can ask help from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after doing the follow steps:

1. Uninstalling Java JDK, Ruby, Node, force cli and Sublime and deleting all left over files from those program (C:/users/myuser/AppData/ & C:/Program Data).
2. Installed Sublime, force cli and lightning package to sublime.

It should work and if not, you might want to consider restarting your computer. After that you can install Java JDK, Ruby and Node again.

Even though I still don't know what the problem is, this will certainly make it work.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is more about Force CLI rather than SF.

If you are using the sublime for development and want to continue, then I would prefer mavensmate. Let me know if it helps. http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Installation

Comment: It's strange how I have a few computers with the same operational system, same setup and in some it works fine and on others I get the error mentioned. This make me strongly believe that there is a solution for this problem. I've tried mavensmate but I found that the setup with force cli is a better feet for our team and version control method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ohh I see.. You are using version control as well..!! If this is open source then trying logging a bug with Force Cli. Best of luck

Comment: Not a bad idea. Just did it. https://github.com/heroku/force/issues/192

Comment: Cool. Best of luck in getting this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `package.xml` is in the right place in the directory structure. For me it was

```
./package.xml
./metadata/
./metadata/myStuff/
./metadata/myStuff/...
```

Note that there are two directories between `package.xml` and the actual classes in `myStuff`